# wget authentication fails in docker-compose build but succeeds in docker build Dockerfile

Tags: authentication, dockerfile, wget

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which builds some node regarding to a `Dockerfile`. This `Dockerfile` has a `wget` command as `RUN` which needs authentication. The problem is that authentication step doesn't succeed. I tried `echo` to check command before execution and it was correct; it works fine in the shell, but still getting `Username/Password Authentication Failed`.

This is the command:

```
wget --user $USER --password $PASS $URL
```

Any idea what generates this?

**EDIT 1:**

I have no problem executing above command with `docker build -t myimagename:myimagetag .`

Comment: Show your `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. The issue was using special characters in the `$PASS`. I had to escape those characters with a `\` while passing them to the `docker build` through the shell. I have set `$PASS` in my `.env` file with character escaping too, but it happened that the values contained in the `.env` file are rawly passed to the `Dockerfile` mentioned in `docker-compose.yml`.

Removing `\` escaping in the `.env` file solved everything.